# Abstract controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a standard controller, whose logic the same in other controllers. These are admin panel controllers.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\PageRequest;
use App\Page;
use App\Repositories\PageRepository;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\View\View;

class PageController extends Controller
{
    private const REDIRECT_INDEX = 'PageController@index';
    protected $model;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->model = new PageRepository(new Page());
    }

    public function index(): View
    {
        $pages = $this->model->all();

        return view('pages.index', compact('pages'));
    }

    public function create(): View
    {
        return view('pages.create');
    }

    public function store(PageRequest $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        (new Page($request->all()))->save();

        return redirect()->action(self::REDIRECT_INDEX)->with('status', 'Created');
    }

    public function show(Page $page): View
    {
        return view('pages.show', compact('page'));
    }

    public function edit(Page $page): View
    {
        return view('pages.edit', compact('page'));
    }

    public function update(PageRequest $request, Page $page)
    {
        $page->fill($request->all())->save();

        return redirect()->action(self::REDIRECT_INDEX)->with('status', 'Updated');
    }

    public function destroy(Page $page): RedirectResponse
    {
        $page->delete();

        return redirect()->action(self::REDIRECT_INDEX)->with('status', 'Deleted');
    }
}
```

In other controllers different only

- const REDIRECT_INDEX
- $model
- vies - 'pages.index', 'pages.create' and etc.
- PageRequest $request - request with validation
- Page $page - auto finded row from db by slug

So I have PageController, NewsController, TabController, TypeController with the same logic. How can I abstract?

Comment: Either you make a `CustomDefaultController` which extends `Controller` and let all other controllers extend your new `CustomDefaultController`.
Or you write a `DefaultControllerImplementation` trait and use it in all of your controllers